# Add attribute to product price suffix in woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce, attributes, product

I'm looking for a way to display attribute in price suffix. Snippet works fine on the frontend. But it gives an error while searching for product in the backend.

Snippet:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'oz_product_unit_price_suffix', 20, 2 );
function oz_product_unit_price_suffix( $price, $product ) {

    global $product;
    $unit = $product->get_attribute('pa_enhet');

    if( ! empty( $unit ) ){
        $enhet = wc_get_product_terms( $product->get_id(), 'pa_enhet', array( 'fields' => 'slugs' ) ) ;
        $price .= ' ' . __('/') . $enhet[0];
    }
    
    return $price;
}
```

Debug logs:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_attribute() on null in /home/apps.com/public_html/wp-content/themes/child/functions.php:7
Stack trace:
#0 /home/apps.com/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(308): oz_product_unit_price_suffix()
#1 /home/apps.com/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(205): WP_Hook->apply_filters()
#2 /home/apps.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-product-variable.php(170): apply_filters()
#3 /home/apps.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wpseo-woocommerce/classes/woocommerce-seo.php(1092): WC_Product_Variable->get_price_html()
#4 /home/apps.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wpseo-woocommerce/classes/woocommerce-seo.php(1062): Yoast_WooCommerce_SEO->get_product_price_from_price_html()
#5 /home/apps.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wpseo-woocommerce/classes/woocommerce-seo.php(1302): Yoast_WooCommerce_SEO->get_product_var_price()
#6 /home/apps.com/public_html/wp-content/plugins/wpseo-woocommerce/classes/woocommerce-seo.php(948): Yoast_WooCommerce_SEO->localize_woo_script()
#7 /home/apps.com/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(308): Yoast_WooCommerce_SEO->enqueue_scripts()
#8 /home/apps.com/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(332): WP_Hook->apply_filters()
#9 /home/apps.com/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action()
#10 /home/apps.com/public_html/wp-admin/admin-header.php(118): do_action()
#11 /home/apps.com/public_html/wp-admin/edit.php(407): require_once('/home/apps...')
#12 {main}
  thrown in /home/apps.com/ntqdyrvshq/public_html/wp-content/themes/child/functions.php on line 7
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: The error indicates that the global variable `$product` is null.

Comment: Are you sure that's the correct variable? If the function can be called before that's set, add  `if(!empty($product)) { return; }` to the function to prevent errors.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar  

if (empty($product)) { return; } or if (is_null($product)) { return; } when I added one of these and it worked fine in the backend :)

Comment: You should investigate why the function is being called when `$product` isn't set.